# How to open correctly a local file within Chrome using Selenium WebDriver and Cucumber?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

After passing all test cases( aka scenarios in Cucumber), I'm trying to invoke a method using @After hook Cucumber capability in order to open a report file in Chrome browser. The idea is to display a report file using Selenium WebDriver after all tests are passed. When the Cucumber invokes this @After hook method, Selenium starts, gets this path, but the Chrome doesn't open the report file. Chrome says "Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". But if then I manually click on reload button, the file opens successfully.
Please help me when you are familiar with Cucumber and Selenium.
Thank you in advance.
P.S. Yes, I also tried to replace '\' by '/'

When Selenium tries to access that report html file: 
[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RATTF.png)

My Java code is:

```
@After
public void afterScenarios(){
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Testing\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.manage().window();
          System.out.println("Opening the report...");
          driver.get("C:\\Users\\target\\cucumber-report\\business-acceptance-test1\\index.html");

}
```

Comment: for me it's working totally fine .. just need to refresh one time after url loaded to chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reporting process is not fully complete when the After hook is executing. Try placing the selenium code in a **JVM shutdown hook**. This will make sure everything is completed.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()......);
```

Refer to this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/